# SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I come to you because of a problem with MySQL:

Since some days, without explanation I take this exception :

```
java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: REPLACE INTO `db`.`test_table` (`timestamp`,`database`,`table`,`columns`,`lines`,`before`,`write`,`wait`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:951) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3955) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3926) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1430) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.StatementProxy.executeBatch(StatementProxy.java:116) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.2.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.executeBatch(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.2.jar:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2395) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2316) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2807) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2768) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1651) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3949) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setCatalog(ConnectionImpl.java:5443) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2368) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar:na]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I don't understand this error ? 
The server version is **5.6.19** with mysql-connector **5.1.28**

If someone have any idea I take.
Thanks

EDIT :

The JDBC URL I use : `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1/?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8`

Comment: please share the jdbc url that you are using..

Comment: the URL : `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1/?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8`

Comment: can you please try this instead  `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1/db?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=‌​utf-8`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finaly, I found the root cause of my problem. This is not the database inside the URL, just a consequence.

The problem come from JDBC parameters I use :

- cachePrepStmts=true
- prepStmtCacheSize=250
- prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
- **useServerPrepStmts=true**

The last one, with MySQL 5.6 is really not recommended because of bugs. So I have remove all statement cache parameters and now my code run correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You must have forgot to mention the database/schema name in your jdbc connection URL. Please find the below message in stack trace

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected`

Comment: Not look the stacktrace : `REPLACE INTO `db`.`test_table` ...` the database is mention

Comment: have you mentioned something like `jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db` in any config file? may be in xml or in Java config, and you must have missed the `test_db` part

Comment: no, I use the same pool for multiple database, each query have the table prefixed by database.

Comment: are you saying that the same URL worked for other quires and is failing only for this one?

Comment: Yes, I have dev, itg, prp environment with no problem. Impossible to reproduce outside the prod environment.
I will try to add default database to the URL

Comment: Add database to URL seems to solve the problem. Thank for your help